# Change size of a layer from Drawable[] with 2 layers

Tags: android, layout, resources, drawable, layer

I need to change the size of the second layer of an Drawable[].
I have the following code:

```
hLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        DisplayMetrics metrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (coupons != null) {
                                int coupSize = coupons.size();
                                final int itemWidth = (width / 3);
                                final int itemHeight = (height / 3);
                                hLayout.removeAllViews();
                                for (int i = 0; i < coupSize; i++) {
                                    Coupon coupon = coupons.get(i);
                                    if (coupon.getImage() != null) {
                                        RelativeLayout parent = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                        parent.setLayoutParams(linearparams);
                                        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                                        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
                                        // iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                                        LayoutParams checkBoxParams = new LayoutParams();
                                        cb.setId(i);
                                        checkBoxParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                        checkBoxParams.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeListener);
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(itemWidth, itemHeight);
                                        imageParams.height = itemHeight;
                                        imageParams.width = itemWidth;
                                        imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, cb.getId());
                                        if (cb.getId() == 0) {
                                            imageParams.topMargin = 72;
                                        }
                                        parent.addView(cb, checkBoxParams);
                                        parent.addView(iv, imageParams);
                                        hLayout.addView(parent);
                                        //ImageUtil.loadImage(coupon.getImage(), iv, itemWidth, itemHeight, "", false, getActivity());
                                        Bitmap b  =Util.generateEAN("9310779300005", getActivity());
                                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);
                                        System.out.println("------------b : "+b);
                                        //iv.setImageBitmap(b);
                                        Resources r = getResources();
                                        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
                                        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.coupon1);

                                        layers[1] = d;
                                        layers[1].setAlpha(200);

                                        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
                                        iv.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }, 200);
```

I tried with layers[1].setBounds(left, top, right, bottom); but had no luck, i don't know what else to try.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used `Canvas` class to achieve this purpose. Please have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Thor this is an answer, just not a very helpful or detailed one

Answer (score 2):

I just do this in my code....here I change the size of `layer[0]`. It works . Just change the values in `layerDrawable.setLayerInsert(layer index,left,top,right,bottom)` like:

```
        Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];

        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gi);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.url);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
                  // left top right bottom
        layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 600, 600, 600, 600);

        iv1.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```